# Pythonic way to convert two adjacent list elements to a tuple and preserve rest of list

Tags: python, list, tuples

I'm looking for an elegant way to convert

```
lst = [A, B, C, D, E..]
```

to

```
lst = [A, B, (C, D), E]
```

so given that I want to do this on index 2 and 3 but preserve the list. Is there an elegant way to perform this? I was looking with a lambda function but I did not see it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just alter in-place:

```
lst[2:4] = [tuple(lst[2:4])]
```

The slice assignment ensures we are replacing the old elements with the contents of the list on the right-hand side of the assignment, which contains just the one tuple.

Demo:

```
>>> lst = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
>>> lst[2:4] = [tuple(lst[2:4])]
>>> lst
['A', 'B', ('C', 'D'), 'E']
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
lst[2] = lst[2], lst.pop(3)
```

or more generally:

```
lst[i] = lst[i], lst.pop(i+1)
```

However you must insure that both indices are valid in avoid`IndexError`exceptions.